# Null exception in filling a querystring by mocking framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, constructor, mocking, query-string

There is a simple controller that a querystring is read in constructor of it.

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
 {
    parivate string productName;

    public ProductController()
    {
       productName = Request.QueryString["productname"];
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = productName;

        return View();
    }
 }
```

Also I have a function in unit test that create an instance of this Controller and I fill the querystring by a Mock object like below.

```
[TestClass]
public class ProductControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var querystring = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection { { "productname", "sampleproduct"} };
        var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.QueryString).Returns(querystring);

        var controller = new ProductController();
        controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;


        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Request.QueryString["productname"] is null in constructor of ProductController when I run test unit.

Is ther any way to fill a querystrin by a mocking and get it in constructor of a control?

Comment: Did you ever solved this problem? I just had the same issue

Answer (score 4):

> There is a simple controller that a querystring is read in constructor of it.

You shouldn't be doing this and such controller shouldn't exist. The controller context is not yet initialized in the constructor and it will fail not only for the unit test but in real.

You should use the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28VS.90%29.aspx) method where you have access to the request context.

Comment: Why isn't this marked as the answer? I had a similar issue where I needed to access the request context, and this solution was better than I hoped for.